# Need jekyll back-end Solution

Tags: jekyll

> What Is The Best Solution For Jekyll Back-end Or Admin Template Or
>   Dashboard ? I Am Finding Free Resource For Jekyll Back-end Anyone Can
>   Help me ?

Comment: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin

Comment: Thanks, but it's working in offline only.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is probably no such thing as "the best", since that comes down to opinion driven by individual project needs/requirements. Can you explain what you mean by back-end?

Since Jekyll is static, I'm assuming what your looking for is a content management system that works with Jekyll built sites. Maybe similar to what you'd see in non static solutions such as WordPress.

There are several CMS options for Jekyll but my personal favorite is http://cloudcannon.com/

Its not free but does have a 30 day free trial and excellent learning resources at https://learn.cloudcannon.com/.

There are also other solutions you can easily find with a quick google or github.com search for "jekyll cms". Additionally you might try posting this question at the https://talk.jekyllrb.com/ forums if you can't find a solution that fits your specific needs.